# couldn't understand app review process on google play

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

Does google review app everytime when we upload new android app bundle because I uploaded new .aab file in production and status is written "in review".

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does review the app every time except for the internal test track.

Comment: Google only reviews app releases on Production, Beta and Alpha testing tracks. It does not do a review on the internal track, unless it is your first release.